# Two STL threads wait on a third thread—do with joinable?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, stl, thread-safety

I want two threads (let's call them t1 and t2) to wait for one other thread, t0. Let's simplify matters and say t1 and t2 are both worker threads. I don't think the following code will work correctly.

```
/* ... code both t1 and t2 run ... */
if (t0.joinable()) { 
  /* race condition here */
  t0.join();
}
```

It's possible for both t1 and t2 to get true for `joinable`, and then whichever `join`s first wins and the other one probably segfaults—right? So what is the **correct** way to have two threads wait on a single third thread?

Is there a way to do this just with joins of the STL, or does t0 need to set some sort of (atomic) done flag or use a condition variable?

Comment: By STL you mean the `std` library?  The [STL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library) has no threading support

Comment: They can atomically pick a thread to join the third thread, and the selected thread notifies the other once it completes the join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *nix way is to have the parent wait for its children termination.

t0 will have to signal it's done doing whatever they're waiting for. Like you said, conditional variable is a simple way to do it, or just a flag would be simplest, but t1 and t2 would have to poll it.

If you want them to sleep-wait then you'd have to use a conditional variable.

Comment: It's more like an elder sibling—t1 and t2 can do a lot of work in parallel with t0 but at a certain point they need t0 to finish before they do. I can rewrite this with a CV but it does add some cross-object complexity.

Comment: So, why not use a simple flag? you can make it atomic, or volatile would be the same in that case.

Comment: went with the atomic flag approach

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::async` and `future` and `shared_future`.

Replace the `std::thread` with a `std::async` call, possibly returning `void` (or whatever the thread will produce, ideally).  Then take the produced `future`, and move it into a `shared_future`.

Finally, both threads can wait on that `shared_future`.  If there is a data packet, both will get a copy of it.